# Hide the datepicker on blur event

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery

I am trying to add an event blur on input in order to hide a calendar.
The plugin I am using to show the calendar is the foliowing [eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker).

Here is the source code http://jsfiddle.net/KLpq7/75/

```
var inputs = $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true
});

inputs.on('blur', function () {
          console.log($(this));
          // I would like to hide just the date picker
          //$(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try this:

```
var inputs = $('.datepicker').datepicker({
format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
autoclose: true}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
         $(this).blur();
         $(this).datepicker('hide');
     });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KLpq7/82/

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as such. The answer from AntoJs makes actually picking a date impossible because the blur event gets called before the click can set the date value in the input.

Answer (score 3):

```
    inputs.on('blur', function () {
        inputs.datepicker('hide');
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately it works partially because the datepicker is hidden but the date is not filled in the input.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/202)* -- if you use "datepicker" as the class for your inputs, it will interfere  with the datepicker code, because `datepicker` is also the class used for the picker pane.  Using a different class for your pickers should fix the issue for now.

* There aren't any *open* tickets for it at the moment, but it is acknowledged as a minor bug

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KLpq7/84/) updated fiddle.  I think that since you were using a class selector there was some conflicts in the blur event handler.  I have separated each calendar picker by ID and it seems to work fine now.